# C++ basic qt question

Tags: c++, qt, view, matrix

Does someone know a fast way to add the ability to rotate and move a 3D model using Qt?

Obviously, I have to make changes to the world matrix based on the mouse and keyboard movements, and hence I should somehow handle the appropriate `mouseEvents` and `keyboardEvens`.

*For a 3d camera this seems a bit tricky and although I could implement it myself, I'd better stick to something ready.*

Does anyone know or have an example which handles this kind of actions and reflects them to the world matrix?

Thank you.

Comment: How about embedding an OpenGL widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/modelviewer/) might be what you're looking for.  It is an example that loads .obj models and allows you to rotate them with the mouse.  It also shows you how to render Qt dialogs within the OpenGL scene.